# Salesforce integration with D2L Brightspace - oauth2.0 issues

Tags: oauth-2.0, desire2learn

I'm working with a client who is going to use Brightspace API's to build an integration between Salesforce and D2L's Brightspace. 
We are currently trying to utilize Oauth2.0 to authenticate the necessary API calls.  We have created the required Oauth App in their Brightspace site.

### when sending the following request:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
//req.setEndpoint('callout:D2L');
String clientId = 'retrieved from registered app in Bspace';
String clientSecret = 'retrieved from registered app in Bspace';
String refreshToken = '';
String scope = 'core:*:*';
String redirectUri = 'https://test.salesforce.com/services/auth/oauth/00D0S0000000VTwUAM/D2L';
req.setEndpoint('https://auth.brightspace.com/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=' + clientId + '&client_secret=' +clientSecret+'&scope=' +scope);

//String reqbody = 'grant_type=refresh_token&client_id='+clientId+'&client_secret='+clientSecret;
//req.setBody(reqbody);
//req.setheader('client_id',clientId);
//req.setheader('client_secret',clientSecret);
req.setheader('grant_type','refresh_token');
//req.setheader('response_type','code');
req.setheader('redirect_uri',redirectUri);
//req.setheader('refresh_token',refreshToken);
req.setMethod('GET');
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
System.debug(res.getBody());
System.debug('Response: ' + res);
```

---

They are receiving the following...

Error message:
System.HttpResponse[Status=Found, StatusCode=302]

Any thoughts on what is wrong here?

mike

Answer (score 0):

Got this working.  Issue was due to the configuration settings of the 'D2L' app in Salesforce.  It's critical that SF send the client_id and client_secret to the D2L auth service in the header (not body) of the HTTP request.  There are SF configurations such as "Generate Authorization Header" and "Allow Merge Fields in HTTP Header" that define this.
Once the app can authenticate, Salesforce admins can use 'apex' to deliver the api call to Brightspace, simply calling out the app.  i.e.

req.setEndpoint('callout:D2L/d2l/api/lp/1.9/enrollments/users/1928/orgUnits/6773');

where 'D2L' is the configured app.

mike